# Add style for parent element

Tags: css, typescript, google-maps-markers, openinfowindowhtml

I want to write style for the parent element of the child class .gm-style .gm-style-iw. I used :parent as well but it is not working. These two class are dynamically appear in the DOM.

I am stuck here. Please help.

Comment: no its not working

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible with pure CSS you could do it with Javascript but there is no option to do this with pure CSS, sorry.

The `:parent` is a concept of how it could look like when it's implemented.

**Edit - JS**

```
let a = document.querySelectorAll('.gm-style');
for(let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].parentNode.classList.add('');
}
```

this should work even in IE11 just insert the class you want to add to the parent with the styles it should get.

Comment: I am using angular 5 and so typescript. How can it be done then?